# Mikvah erev Yom kippur

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, mikvah-ritual-bath

Do you have an obligation to go to the mikvah erev Yom Kippur.

Answer (score 12):

Rambam writes in his preface to his Commentary on the Mishnah that one who rejects "*minhagei Yisrael*" - customs that are considered valid and universal in Torah Judaism, on him the verse is applied "One who knocks down a fence will be bitten by a snake." (Definitely something bad!)

That being said, the custom to immerse in the *mikvah* on *erev Yom HaKippurim* is brought in Shulhan Aruch, O.C. Siman 606, S'if 5. It is **universally accepted among all Torah Observant Halachic authorities, Ashkenazic, Sefardic, Yemenite, etc.** The Aruch HaShulhan uses the wording "*Nahagu kohl Yisrael* (**All Jews are accustomed**...). (Ibid. Si'if 5) It definitely fits the term "*minhag Yisrael*"!

It is referred to as a *mitzvah*, not as *hovah*, literally meaning that it is not obligatory. (Kitzur SA 131,6) This **just** means that the precautions taken for an immersion that is actually required by the Torah do not apply. It does not mean that the minhag is optional. If one absolutely **cannot** immerse (e.g. too sick), then the pouring of 9 *kabin* of water over the body is acceptable for this immersion. There are those who maintain that standing completely under a fully opened shower for a while would fulfill the 9 *kabin* requirement. (Halichos Olam Page 179)

Comment: Not sure I could say "universally accepted."  (Need a sociologist to take a survey or something; I know plenty of Orthodox Jews who don't.)  Rabbi Rakefet has a lecture on yutorah (don't recall which) in which he said his mentor, Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik zt'l, implied that he didn't go to mikvah erev yom kippur.

Comment: If Rabbi Solovietchik did not go to the Mikveh that does not mean that it is not accepted universally by all Halachic authorities. If he had a personal reason to not got to the mikveh does not mean he did not pour 9 kabin over himself by standing under the shower. Never bring a proof from a Maaseh Rav if the Rav was not asked why he is doing/not doing so.

Comment: And when I said universally accepted I was referring to all written relevant Halakhic sources from the Mishnah Berurah, Aruch Hashulhan up through the Rishonim, such as the Kolbo and Rambam. BTW the lashon of the Aruch HaShulhan is "Nahagu Kohl Yisrael".

Comment: where is the referenced Rambam?

Comment: @mevaqesh, Beer HaGolah OC 606-4 n7 brings it from the Tashbetz in the name of R"M which is the acronym that is used for Rambam in earlier sources.

Comment: @mevaqesh Depends which Tashbetz--if it is the talmid of the Maharam mi-Rothenburg, it probably refers to the Maharam.

Comment: But I believe the Rambam writes that he was makpid on tevilas Ezra, so I don't know how surprising it would be if the Rambam did mention it.

Comment: @mevaqesh And in fact in this case, it does refer to Maharam mi-Rothenburg (as confirmed by Shulchan Aruch, Friedman ed.)

Comment: @wfb good catch. In that case Yahu should edit the Rambam out of the sources.

Comment: @wfb excellent catch! Rambam is coming out; but your point about Tevillas Ezra makes a compelling case of possibility that he may have also gone on erev Yom Hakkipurim.

Comment: And @mevaqesh great catch regarding which Tashbetz! The truth is that many poskim and Acharonim use Rashbetz for the Sefardishe one.

Comment: What source do you have that Yemenites have a custom to immerse themselves on Erev Yom kippur?

Comment: @mevaqesh my recollection is that I saw it in Kafich's Halichot Teiman, but it has been a while since I looked in that sefer and I could be wrong on that one. I will bl"n dig up my pdf copy of it to check . . .

Comment: I've also heard it claimed that there were those who would make a bracha on this tevilah, although that this is not the custom today. See [link](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/4442/jewish/Erev-Yom-Kippur.htm) where it quotes this as the opinion of the Geonim.